# NullPointerException ao ligar o servidor

Tags: java, socket, multithreading, nullpointerexception, cliente-servidor

Estou fazendo um programa em Java de servidor/cliente. Quando inicializo a classe servidor aparece-me o erro

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Deixo abaixo o código para que me possam ajudar a resolver o problema:

```
public class Servidor implements Runnable {

    HashMap<String, ServerOutput> utilizadorLigados;
    private ArrayList<Mensagem> listaMensagensEntregar = new ArrayList<Mensagem>();
    ServerSocket server = null;
    private int port;
    private Thread serverthread;


    public Servidor(int port) {

        this.port = port;
        utilizadorLigados = new HashMap<String, ServerOutput>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (this) {
            this.serverthread = Thread.currentThread();

        while (true) {

        Socket cliente = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("1");
                cliente = this.server.accept();
                System.out.println("2");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao aceitar o cliente", e);
            }

            new Thread(new ServerInput(this, cliente)).start();
            System.out.println("Servidor ligado");
            }
        }
    }

    public void abrirPortasServidor() {
        try {
            this.server = new ServerSocket(port);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public HashMap<String, ServerOutput> getUtilizadorLigados() {
        return utilizadorLigados;
    }

    public ServerOutput getServerOutput(String clinte) {

        return utilizadorLigados.get(clinte);
    }

}
```

Na consola , o programa faz o sysout "1" do run, mas nao faz o "2" portanto o problema está na linha `cliente = this.server.accept();`

Ajudem-me por favor!

Comment: ServerSocket server = null;

Answer (score 1):

Você deve criar uma instancia de `ServerSocket`, você está declarando ela como um objeto nulo

tente:

```
  @Override
public void run() {

    synchronized (this) {
        this.serverthread = Thread.currentThread();

        //Inicializa o server
        this.server = new ServerSocket();

    while (true) {

    Socket cliente = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("1");
            cliente = this.server.accept();
            System.out.println("2");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao aceitar o cliente", e);
        }

        new Thread(new ServerInput(this, cliente)).start();
        System.out.println("Servidor ligado");
        }
    }
}
```